# OmniChanelFlow with Einstein Bot - transfert to queue

Tags: einstein, queue, omnichannel, einstein-chatbot

I am having trouble to use the Omnichannel flow with my einstein chat bot.

In My Einstein bot:

1. I added an action connected to a flow. This flow define based on specific parameter to which Queue I would like to route my Chat
2. With my queue Id defined,  and I then launch a subflow with an Omni Channel Flow in order to route my Chat.
3. I added as recordId my routableId and my QueueId

for some reason NOTHING happen. I do not get any error ..
In the recordId should I pass my routableId ? The chat transcript ID ?

What am I missing ?